# QT Regular Expression getting contents between brackets

Tags: regex, qt5.5

I want to split an expression getting the contents between brackets:

eg. An expression could look like this:

```
    (center:SCREEN)-(25%:SCREEN_WIDTH)
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
    QStringList lstTerms = strProcessed.split("/\(([^)]+)\)/")
```

But this only returns:

```
    (center:SCREEN)-(25%:SCREEN_WIDTH)
```

What I want is the array to contain two element, in the case of the example above:

```
    [0] center:SCREEN
    [1] 25%:SCREEN_WIDTH
```

Thank you @noob, final routine:

```
QRegularExpression regex("(?<=\\()[^)]*(?=\\))");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matches = regex.globalMatch(strProcessed);
QStringList slstTerms;

while( matches.hasNext() ) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = matches.next();

    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        slstTerms.append(match.captured(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could at least try `"\\(([^()]+)\\)"` to limit the pattern to matching what is inside `(....)`. BTW, it is a *matching* pattern, not a *splitting* one. You do not need any regex delimiters and the backslashes must be doubled.

Comment: Thank you, however that expression only returns 1 result which is the same as I have already posted.

Comment: Try `QRegExp rx("\\(([^()]+)\\)");
    QStringList lstTerms;
    
    int pos;
    while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
       lstTerms << rx.cap(1);
    }`

Comment: Just tried this, nothing returned at all.

Comment: Using `QRegularExpression regex("\\(([^()]+)\\)");` and `slstTerms.append(match.captured(1));` you could use a much simpler and efficient regex I suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `look around` assertions. Keep the global mode on with `g`

**Regex:** `(?<=\()[^)]*`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\()` looks behind for  a `(` i.e opening parenthesis.
- `[^)]*` matches content within parenthesis until a closing parenthesis `)` is met.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qE1lV8/3)**

---

**Update:**

I have changed regex a little. Removed the `look ahead` part `(?=\))` because it was unnecessary. `[^)]*` itself is checking till a closing parenthesis is met.